# amcharts not rendering India map correctly in worldmap

Tags: amcharts

While amcharts shows the India map correctly (showing the disputed regions as part of India) when displaying only India (http://jsfiddle.net/zxhseguw/5/)

`"dataProvider": {
    "map": "indiaLow",
    "areas": [ {
      "id": "IN-KA",
      "value": 4447100,
    }, {
        "id": "IN-UP",
      "value": 38763
    }] 
  },`

it shades it differently when rendering it on world map (http://jsfiddle.net/zxhseguw/6/)

`"dataProvider": {
    "map": "worldLow",
    "areas": [ {
      "id": "IN",
      "value": 4447100,
    }, {
        "id": "AU",
      "value": 387633
    }] 
  },`

I wonder, if there is a way to make it render India correctly, just like its possible in Google Charts by setting origin='India'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you're referring to the region around Kashmir, correct? Try using `worldIndiaLow` instead of `worldLow`, which includes more of that disputed area as part of India.

```
"dataProvider": {
    "map": "worldIndiaLow",
    "areas": [ {
      "id": "IN",
      "value": 4447100,
    }, {
        "id": "AU",
      "value": 387633
    }] 
  },
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zxhseguw/7/)